# Calculate Hour Difference Between Two Times In a Day(s)

Tags: java, time

Just wanted to know if this function's results will always hold?

```
private int calcHourDiff(int start, int end) {

    int diff;

    if(start > end) {
        diff = ((2400 - start) + end) / 100;
    } else if(start < end) {
        diff = (end - start) / 100;
    } else {
        diff = 0;
    }

    return diff;

}
```

Functions are passed in as military time and it should return the amount of hours in between. Passed in values will always be "easy" numbers such as 1200, 1400, 2100 not 2134 or 015. It needs to be able to properly calculate all possible cases, will this function hold?

I had trouble for values ranging from the night (8PM or 2000) to the next day (6AM or 600) and I think this should fix it?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Should it take in account daylight saving time?

Comment: You don't need the unconditional `else`; it's already handled by the `else if`.

Comment: You can use JUnit to test if it holds.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I assume you mean that the `else if` should be changed to an `else` to handle the `0` case.

Comment: No daylights savings. And I think I need the unconditional else to initialize diff in case the two hours are identical, hence 0 hours.

Comment: I already tested all values I can think of. Not sure if there were more values I didn't think of or a better way to go about it. Because I didn't derive ((2400 - start) + end), it just something I made up that made sense for a specific example.

Comment: @skynorth you can initialise your diff variable to 0 and remove the unconditional `else`.

Comment: When it comes to date/time manipulation, in 99% of the cases I prefer using a library rather than rolling my own. Even simple tasks tend to grow more complicated over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be different, here's a version without any conditionals at all:

```
private int calcHourDiff(int start, int end) {
    return ((end - start + 2400) % 2400) / 100;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Should I divide the result of that by 100 to get the hours?

Comment: +1 Very slick, but given how long it took me to figure out that this was right, I would suggest it might be too slick. Maybe his teammates are smarter than me though. ;)

Comment: @John: This is somewhat idiomatic.  It's almost equivalent to `(end - start) % 2400`, except that whether that gives the "correct" result for negative input is implementation-defined, so offset the range to ensure it's always positive.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good.

When comparing two numbers, x and y, there are only 3 possible outcomes: x == y, x < y, x > y

Your if block covers all three, and the math for each condition looks good.

Just would be worried about the assumption that the data passed will always be "easy" and correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int calcHourDiff(int start, int end) {

  int newEnd = (start > end)?end + 2400 : end;
  return (newEnd - start) / 100;
}
```